# Is it possible to connect to sites neatly with Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm extracting information from an anime site with Jsoup for one android app, but I'm having trouble with a certain part of the site.

When I access the address http://www.URL.com/anime?page=1 it shows me a series of anime in a disorganized way.

When I click to display only the animes with the letter "A" the link changes to http://www.URL.com/anime?letra=A but it does not show me all, in the footer there are buttons to change the page, however these buttons have exactly the link http://www.URL.com/anime?page=1 only now displaying in an orderly fashion only the animals with the letter A.

Is there any way for Jsoup to first access the http://www.URL.com/anime?letra=A, then save the information that is accessing that site and then access http://www.URL.com / anime? page = 1, 2, 3 and etc ...?

How to navigate between pages I already know.

I'm using a translator, I'm sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: You could see if http://www.URL.com/anime?letra=A&page=1 works so you can do it in one request with Jsoup.

Comment: If I try to access this URL directly it brings me the content listing at random rather than in alphabetical order.

I have to login first by choosing the letter and only then can I navigate it.

But I do not know how to do this with jsoup.